# Need help to modify my SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to modify my existing SQL query (number 1) given below. Firstly, I need to know if it is possible to do what I want (number 2). If yes, then what are the ways I can do it.

```
--**(Number 1)** What I currently have      

SELECT  Column1
    FROM  dbo.Table1
    WHERE ColumnValue1 = 'One'
    AND scalarFunctionResult(Var) = 'Word1'
    AND ColumnValue2 = "Word2"


--*(Number 2)* What I need      
SELECT  Column1
    FROM  dbo.Table1
    WHERE ColumnValue1 = 'One'
    AND SomeVariable IN (scalarFunctionResult(Var) = 'Word1', 'WordA')
-- Perform a query based 
--on value of SomeVariable, Please read pseudo code below 
    AND ColumnValue2 = "Word2"

--Pseudo code for logic
--if(SomeVariable = 'Word1') then run query ABCD,
--else if(SomeVariable = 'WordA') then run some other query EFGH
```

Comment: Can you please explain why do you want to check Var value against some static value "Word1" inside the Where clause of the query? Does it make any difference in the result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple `OR`

```
SELECT Column1
  FROM dbo.Table1
 WHERE ColumnValue1 = 'One'
   AND ((@SomeVariable = 'Word1' AND <the condition ABCD>)
        OR
        (@SomeVariable = 'WordA' AND <the condition EFGH>))
```

Effectively, you get the result from either ABCD when `@Somevariable = 'Word1'`, or from the other condition "query" EFGH when `@Somevariable = 'WordA'`.

e.g.

```
SELECT Column1
  FROM dbo.Table1
 WHERE ColumnValue1 = 'One'
   AND ((dbo.scalarFunctionResult(@SomeVariable) = 'Word1' AND ColumnValue2 = "Word2")
        OR
        (dbo.scalarFunctionResult(@SomeVariable) = 'WordA' AND ColumnValue3 = "Word3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to figure out how to create IF statement in SQL? Not sure I understand your question correctly.

If this is so here is the reference from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933214%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) . You might not need it in this case though as RichardTheKiwi showed.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something like an IF. But, I will look into all the answers I get.